# function is not iterable with "new Map()"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm creating a network graph with d3.js.

I want to group the nodes just like [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/XavierGimenez/a8e8c5e9aed71ba96bd52332682c0399).
The example uses d3 v4, but I'm using v6.

In the [migration guide](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide) it says the `(d3).map()` doesn't work anymore(it gives me an error when I use `.map()`) and I have to use `new Map()`.
But when I do this I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: function is not iterable (cannot read property
> Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
> at new Map ()

This is my code atm:

```js
const groupIds = new Set(nodes.map(function(n) {
  //get ids
}))
  .values()
  new Map(function(departmentId) {
    return {
      departmentId: departmentId,
      count: nodes.filter(function(n) {
        //some code
      }).length
    };
  })
  .filter(function(department) {return department.count > 0;})
  new Map(function(department) {return department.departmentId;});
```

I also tried `let map = new Map()`, but gives the same error.

How can I use the `new Map()` in this context?

When I use `.map()` instead of `new Map()` it says:

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).values(...).map is not a function

Comment: The Map constructor accepts an iterable. Note that the [`Map` *object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is nothing to do with [`.map()` *method*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). One is a data structure with key-value relationships, the other a method to convert a data structure into another. Most often (in JS) it's to convert an array into another array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map` is not related to `map`: *Map* is a constructor used to create an instance of *Map*, and *.map* is a method used process every element of array.

If you use *Set* just to create an array of unique values you can omit *.values* execution and just convert your result *Set* to array:

```
[...new Set([1,1,1,1,1,2,1])]
// or 
Array.from(new Set([1,1,1,1,1,2,1]))
```